How can I create two connected io.ReadWriteClosers for testing purposes
I'm trying to run some tests on a network application of mine. I'd like to avoid creating a socket for each test, so I thought I'd use io.Pipe from the standard library. However it only provides a io.PipeReader, io.PipeWriter pair. I need two connected io.ReadWriteClosers
func TestEndpoints() {
    // Create pipeEndpoint1 and pipeEndpoint2. Both should implement  
    // io.ReadWriteCloser

    e1 := makeEndpoint(pipeEndpoint1)
    e2 := makeEndpoint(pipeEndpoint2)

    // Run some test
}
 
func makeEndpoint(rwc io.ReadWriteCloser) *Endpoint {
    // 
}

Is there a way to create two connected io.ReadWriteClosers?

wdym by two connected ? like MultiWriter or TeeReader

I mean connected in the same way that PipeReader and PipeWriter are connected, i.e. a write on one can be read on the other. But I need it bidirectional and closeable.

You can just make two pipes, one for each direction.

net.Pipe basically implements this for you (see this question). Take heed of the comment noting that this is synchronous (can lead to some confusing deadlocks that would not happen with a real connection - io.Pipe has the same issue).

If you want to test something related to network, how about using httptest package like this, https://go.dev/play/p/YLR2jCk9JN5?

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in the standard library, so this is what I did instead:
type PipeBidirectional struct {
    r *io.PipeReader
    w *io.PipeWriter
}

func NewPipes() (*PipeBidirectional, *PipeBidirectional) {
    r1, w1 := io.Pipe()
    r2, w2 := io.Pipe()

    return &PipeBidirectional{r1, w2}, &PipeBidirectional{r2, w1}
}

func (p *PipeBidirectional) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return p.r.Read(b)
}

func (p *PipeBidirectional) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return p.w.Write(b)
}

func (p *PipeBidirectional) Close() error {
    e1 := p.r.Close()
    e2 := p.w.Close()
    if e1 != nil || e2 != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("e1: %w e2: %w", e1, e2)
    }
    return nil
}

